# cocoa/osx - Subclassing NSTextView and method -(BOOL)resignFirstResponder cursor issue

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, subclass, nstextview

I am creating a subclass for NSTExtView and inside I am overiding

```
-(BOOL)resignFirstResponder {

  return YES;

 }
```

Everything works but when when the responder is resigned it leaves a blinking cursor in my textView while the mouse cursor roams free (two cursors!) . Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you overriding `-resignFirstResponder` to begin with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you override `NSTextView -resignFirstResponder`, you're bypassing the code that would remove that cursor.

You should be able to fix the cursor problem by deleting that method or replacing your code with:

```
BOOL canResign = [super resignFirstResponder];

if (canResign) {
    // do some custom stuff
}

return canResign;
```